# Replace no array javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Boa tarde, amigos eu estou com uma problema aqui no javascript. Eu tenho um array, mas a cada indice ele tá adicionando uma aspas duplas, e eu quero retirar elas dali.
Meu código está assim:

```
    dados = new Array();
       $.get(url, function(response){
       for(i in response.content) {
           horario = parseInt(response.content[i].Horario);
           tempo = parseInt(response.content[i].Tempo);
           dados[i]= "["+ horario +", "+ tempo  + "]";
           dados[i] = dados[i].replace(' " ', ' ');
       }

       console.log(dados);

   });
```

E o meu retorno está sendo assim

> ["[0, 54]", "[0, 65]", "[10, 60]"]

E teria que ser assim:

> [[0, 54], [0, 65], [10, 60]]

Alguem sabe se o por que do replace não estar funcionando?

**EDIT**

Eu esqueci de mencionar a parte importante, eu vou usar esse array pra um chart
e o modelo de dados que ele lê é assim:

```
data: [ [0, 54], [5, 65], [10, 60] ]
```

por isso eu já concatenei ali nele o abre "chaves" em cada um dos indices

Comment: Luan da forma que você esta fazendo esta criando um array monodimensional de String, e o que você deseja é um array bidimensional de Int, para isso você tera de atribuir em `dados[i]` o array com a hora,tempo

Answer (score 1):

Bom vamos converter o comentário para pratica:

> Luan da forma que você esta fazendo esta criando um array monodimensional de String, e o que você deseja é um array bidimensional de Int, para isso você tera de atribuir em dados[i] o array com a hora,tempo

```
dados = new Array();
    $.get(url, function(response){
    for(i in response.content) {
            horario = parseInt(response.content[i].Horario);
            tempo = parseInt(response.content[i].Tempo);
            dados[i] = new Array();
            dados[i].push(horario);
            dados[i].push(tempo);
    }
    console.log(dados);
});
```

Comment: Olá Guilherme, valeu pela ajuda. Então, eu tenho que jogar esse array num chart.js que tem como padrão de data do jeito que eu mandei ali. Seria assim: data: [ [1,20], [2,60]  ]. Eu editei a minha pergunta pra explicar melhor

Comment: desse jeito que você colocou, como faço pra jogar no data do chart nesse formato que ele necessita?

Comment: @LuanGabriel teria que especificar qual biblioteca você esta usando, mas creio que só `chart['data'] = dados;`

Comment: estou usando o Chart.js

Answer (score 1):

Todas as respostas resolveram seu problema, mas não responderam o que você perguntou, então aqui vai a resposta da sua pergunta, só pra casos futuros (o que te responderam está correto)

Seu replace não funcionou por erro de sintaxe.

a forma correta seria

dados[i] = dados[i].replace(/"/, '');

O valor a ser substituído tem que ser cercado por barras, e se quiser remover algo precisa colocar uma string vazia depois da virgula, não uma string com um espaço dentro(caso contrário, vai ter um espaço antes e um depois de cada chave).

Answer (score 0):

O questão é que quanto você substitui '"' por ' ' ainda tem um array de string. Aonde cada registro contem um conjunto de [numero, numero]. E ai o console do navegador está te pregando uma peça. A forma do console apresentar um array de string sempre vai ser ["valor1", "valor2"] e etc...

Isso da a impressão que o replace não está funcionando quando na verdade está. Porém como falei ainda é um array de string. Se você colocar um console mostrando somente o replace verá que está certo.

Para resumir utilize o eval para transforma o array de string em array de números veja:

```js
var dados = [];
for(i in [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]) {
 dados[i]= "["+ i +", "+ 5  + "]";
}

console.log(dados);

for(i in [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]) {
 dados[i] = eval(dados[i]);
}

console.log(dados);
```